# Customized UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I just want to confirm that which is the better way for handling the highly customized table view, is it by using the nib file or writing the code for each element ourself.

Comment: What does "highly customized table view"? We need more info to be able to answer this question precisely.

Comment: by highly customized i mean to say that there are lots of components like labels and images which are displaying the data from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked not only in regard to UITableViews. You can see some tests here:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/load-from-nib-or-construct-views-in.html

If the cells are very complex, it is easier to create a nib file for the cell, like here
http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

Memory wise, I can't tell you for sure. 
But considering you are talking about a highly customized table view, using nibs is better because you can actually see the modifications. This makes it easier for you. Otherwise it would be a real pain to create a highly customized cell only by code, not to mention that it would make it nearly impossible to be edited by someone else than a programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, can you suggest me the better way to handle cells with dynamic heights. What is the best way to handle the tableview cell in which components can vary and the layout of the components also.

Comment: you can implement - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath for the cells with dynamic height ... For the layout, the basic cellForRowAtIndexPath should do the trick. You simply display different cells according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to create a separate nib only for your cell layout as described here: [UITableViewController with custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539960/uitableviewcontroller-with-custom-uitableviewcell/)